# how to prepend a line or replace the first line with awk or sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I'd like to know how I can inset a line using awk

currently i created this script:

```
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS="\t";} { print $1,$3,$11,"10"; }' boinc.txt | sed 1d
```

and the output is:

[image]

it works great!

however, i would like to prepend a line to the beginning of the output specifying the header names like "key, price, barcode, days"

desired output would be something like this:

```
+------------------------------------+
|    key   price   barcode   days    |
+------------------------------------+
| 16112   $23.94  5014682600194   10 |
| 16126   $1.99   019688104122    10 |
| 16152   $7.99   099923118527    10 |
| 16178   $8.99   3366750130396   10 |
| 16233   $5.99   7318590001615   10 |
| 16236   $6.99   410965078691    10 |
| 16257   $8.99   7318590000397   10 |
| 16279   $5.99   7318590000113   10 |
| 16282   $5.99   7318590001387   10 |
| 16318   $6.99   723721898120    10 |
+------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t"; print "key", "price", "barcode", "days" } 
NR > 1 { print $1, $3, $11, "10" }' boinc.txt
```

**Note:** You don't need `sed` if you just tell `awk` to skip over first line using `NR>1`

Comment: what does FS=OFS mean?

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов `FS` is nothing but `-F` defined inside `BEGIN` statement or as a variable. We tell `awk` that my `FS` and `OFS` is equal to `\t`. Makes it little shorter and cleaner.

Comment: thank you very much! why is "days" misaligned? http://screencast.com/t/txQOKJTen8

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов It is because the content under barcode is eating into the `tab`. Try `print "key", "price", "barcode", "\tdays"`, though if you are keen on formatting, I would recommend the use of `printf` instead of `print`. Gives you a lot of control.

Comment: im sorry im not undestanding, what do you mean when you say it eats into the tab? if i were to output this into a txt file, would it read it correctly? or would it see that there is no tab between days?

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов There is a tab, you just don't see it because content of `barcode` is larger and eats in to the space. If you write that into a file and do `cat -vet file` you'll see that `tab` exists.